# get specific data from command output

Tags: python

I'll get specific data from OSX command output，sample -

[image]

My code：

```
import os
import json
import plistlib
import subprocess
import datetime

def _LogicalDrive():

    tmp_l = []

    output = subprocess.Popen(
        "diskutil info -all", shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().splitlines()

    for x in output:
        if 'Device Identifier' in x:
            tmp_dict['Identifier'] = x.split(' ')[-1].strip()
        tmp_l.append(tmp_dict)    
    return tmp_l
print _LogicalDrive()
```

I want to get data from specific key，like “Device / Media Name” or others.

Comment: And what is not working in your code? What is the output you get? What is expected instead?

Comment: the output picture is “https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNM1b.png”

Comment: My code will get all items not what I want

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to parse the command output and analyze it.  Its good that you are breaking it apart into separate lines.  Perhaps, in each line split it further with ":\s+" pattern and store the left part of the colon as key and right part as value (perhaps in a dictionary).  You can use that dictionary to query with the key (left part of colon) to get the value.

If you store the pattern of splitting by ":\s+", you can re-use it; perhaps add one more argument where a key has to be specified.

Comment: Can you give sample code？I'm poor about format data of Python

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the output and split each line over `:` taking the left part as key and right as value.

```
def _LogicalDrive():

    tmp_l = []

    output = subprocess.Popen(
        "diskutil info -all", shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

    for x in output.splitlines():
        try:
            key, value = [c.strip() for c in x.split(':') if ':' in x]
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if 'Device Identifier' in x:
            tmp_dict['Identifier'] = value
        tmp_l.append(tmp_dict)

    return tmp_l
```

Comment: Something is wrong：“key, value = [c.strip() for c in x.split(':')]”，ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Updated my answer for that. Didn't take care of blank lines.

Comment: I'm sorry but “ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack” appeared.....

Comment: I may not have the expected output, so just using a regular try except block.

Comment: I tried your code with command output first 5 lines,no error,but fuction output like this：[{'Identifier': 'disk0'}, {'Identifier': ''}, {'Identifier': ''}, {'Identifier': ''}, {'Identifier': ''}]，like what I said before，it will match all lines not what lines of fuction specific

Comment: Use the answer as a guide to your problem, don't exactly copy paste since there is a lot of context that I am missing. For starters, what is `tmp_dict`? Where do you initiliaze it? What's expected output?